# How to draw b-spline curve using this math algorithm

Tags: c++

I have to use this formula in order to draw 3rd degree b-spline curve
[image]

Can someone give me advice what am I doing wrong in my code? Doesn't seem to work properly for me and I am getting this weird results when trying to draw the curve

`segment` is a vector of QPoint, it has x and y

[image]

```cpp
void MyWindow::calculateCurve() {
    QPoint result;
    int m = segment.size();
    int from = m-3;
    int to = m-2;

    for(double t = 0.0; t<=to; t+=0.001){
        result = (pow(-t, 3)+3*pow(t,2)+1)/6*(segment[segment.size()-3])+
                (3*pow(t,3)-6*pow(t,2)+4)/6*(segment[segment.size()-2])+
                (pow(-3*t,3)+3*pow(t,2)+3*t+1)/6*(segment[segment.size()-1]) +
                (pow(t,3)/6)*(segment[segment.size()])
                ;
        draw(result.x(), result.y());
    }

}
```

```
Most often we define a common range for the parameter t (i.e. for
the whole curve, not for each segment separately). We can
e.g. assume that t ∈ [0, m - 2]. Then, for the segment Q3
parameter t varies from t3 = 0 to t4 = 1, for segment
Q4 from t4 = 1 to t5 = 2, and for the last segment Qm from
tm = m - 3 to tm+1 = m - 2.
```

Comment: What is `segment`? Can you please provide a complete example? What's the source for the last quote in your question ("Most often we define [...]")?

Comment: Note that `segment[segment.size()]`, where `segment` is a `std::vector` (or a `QVector`), has undefined behavior, because it accesses out of bounds (the indices sre 0-based).

Answer (score 1):

You have written `pow(-3*t,3)`, which means (-3t)³, but you should have written `-3*pow(t,3)`, that is, -3(t³):

```
    result = (pow(-t, 3)+3*pow(t,2)+1)/6*(segment[segment.size()-3])+
            (3*pow(t,3)-6*pow(t,2)+4)/6*(segment[segment.size()-2])+
            (-3*pow(t,3)+3*pow(t,2)+3*t+1)/6*(segment[segment.size()-1]) +
            (pow(t,3)/6)*(segment[segment.size()])
            ;
```

Comment: I am not sure about the last line where it says `(segment[segment.size()])`, in the formula it's just Pi, is that how its supposed to be?